# java spring bean annotation @Autowired is not working

Tags: java, spring, javabeans, autowired

I wrote the following code but I cannot make it work. I don't know where is the problem.

All classes are in the "hello" package.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        applicationContext.scan("hello");
        applicationContext.refresh();

        ApplicationService app = new ApplicationService();
        app.run();

        applicationContext.close();
    }


@Component
public class ApplicationService {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("main")
    private SimpleDriverDataSource dataSourcee;

    public void run(){
!!!!!!!!            JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSourcee);
    }


}

@Configuration
public class Config {

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("main")
    public SimpleDriverDataSource getDataSource() {
        SimpleDriverDataSource dataSource = new SimpleDriverDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClass(org.h2.Driver.class);
        dataSource.setUsername("sa");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:h2:mem");
        dataSource.setPassword("");
        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

I tried in a lot of ways and combinations and I still get the following error. I tried without a qualifier, I changed the name of the method in Config, I tried to name the bean differently but I got no results. Where is the problem?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'dataSource' is required
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcAccessor.afterPropertiesSet(JdbcAccessor.java:135)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.<init>(JdbcTemplate.java:169)
    at hello.ApplicationService.run(ApplicationService.java:28)
    at hello.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:12)
```

Comment: Try using 'dataSource' as the qualified name...

Comment: Same result even with the same qualified name.

Comment: The answer in not in the linked topic. I already  tried the solutions.

Comment: I'm just gonna quote the first sentence of the answer given there: _The field annotated `@Autowired` is `null` because Spring doesn't know about the copy of `MileageFeeCalculator` that you created with `new` and didn't know to autowire it._ How did you create your `ApplicationService` object on which you call `run`?

Comment: I got the idea. It's working now. Now you pointed the solution. Thank you!

Comment: Always be careful with `null` in `@Autowired` targets. Spring will **never** (almost) leave such a field as `null`. Instead, it would throw an exception. There must be something else going on in those cases.